# How to add Client Auth to JDK

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate

**Using curl**

I have an endpoint say, "foo.bar.com"

- Inorder to communicate with my endpoint client needs to provide cert&key with passphrase as below and it works.
- I am skipping certificate validation (-k) as the certs are self signed.

.

```
curl -k https://foo.bar.com/get --cert foo-keystore.pem:changeit

{"response":"Hello!"}
```

**Using Javaclient**

I want to hit the same endpoint now with java client with key&cert added to trust store (in my case /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8/jre/security/cacert) But I get HandshakeException with message "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure".

**Client**

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.FileRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.RequestEntity;

public class PostSOAP {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java -classpath <classpath> [-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog=<loglevel>] PostSOAP <url> <soapaction> <filename>]");
            System.out.println("<classpath> - must contain the commons-httpclient.jar and commons-logging.jar");
            System.out.println("<loglevel> - one of error, warn, info, debug, trace");
            System.out.println("<url> - the URL to post the file to");
            System.out.println("<soapaction> - the SOAP action header value");
            System.out.println("<filename> - file to post to the URL");
            System.out.println();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // Get target URL
        String strURL = args[0];
        // Get SOAP action
        String strSoapAction = args[1];
        // Get file to be posted
        String strXMLFilename = args[2];
        File input = new File(strXMLFilename);
        // Prepare HTTP post
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);
        // Request content will be retrieved directly
        // from the input stream
        RequestEntity entity = new FileRequestEntity(input, "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
        post.setRequestEntity(entity);
        // consult documentation for your web service
        post.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", strSoapAction);
        // Get HTTP client
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        // Execute request
        try {
            int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
            // Display status code
            System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
            // Display response
            System.out.println("Response body: ");
            System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } finally {
            // Release current connection to the connection pool once you are done
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

**Env variables**

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/root/foo-certificates.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

**Error**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.proxt.PostSOAP.main(PostSOAP.java:72)
```

**Adding client cert to cacert**

```
keytool -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -importcert -alias <alias-name> -file client.cer
```

Comment: *"I am skipping hostname validation as the certs are self signed"* - that's no reason to skip validation. A self-signed certificate can be validated. In fact, it carries less risk than one issued by a public CA.

Comment: @jww sorry, it was certificate validation (-k)